# How does ASP.Net detect the Culture

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have an ASP.Net site where I have a default.aspx.resx and a default.aspx.no.resx. I have configured my browser (Chrome) with "Norwegian Bokmål (nb)", "Norwegian (no)" and "English (en)".

With Culture and UICulture set to auto in Web.config, I would assume that the no.resx file would be chosen, as that entry is before the english entry. However, unless no is the first option, the default is always chosen. Also, for "Norwegian Bokmål (nb)" the fallback should be "Norwegian (no)".

Am I missing some settings, or is ASP net not fully functional in this aspect, and I need to implement my own culture detection algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, ASP.Net seems buggy when detecting language. My solution was to implement my own culture resolution, that looks at all UserLanguages in order.

Answer (score 0):

[Using resources for localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx)